# Firebase cloud messaging targets are disabled

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I need to send push messages, aka “cloud message”, via firebase console.
I have configured everything that the documentation and examples say (Users, User Properties, User Audiences, Events).
But when I try to compose a new notification, and select a target segment, they are disabled.
Attached is screenshot of target picker that should be enabled:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

From Firebase support:

> If the user properties and audiences are not showing up in the Notifications console, this could mean that your Data-sharing settings is turned off. Please turn this on, and you should start seeing the user properties and audiences in the Notifications console.

Comment: But where is that option?